# Comparing two dates in a textbox

Tags: php, date, textbox, comparison

Lets say in my database I've stored my date and i want to compare it to the current date.
How can i compare it ?

In my first textbox i will echo the data in my database, in the second textbox will be the currentdate

If the  currentdate > data in my database, the first textbox will be red.
if the  currentdate < date in my database, the first texbox will be turned green. Thank you.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Comment: @JohnConde I've tried using comparing those two date using operators but it fails

bascally its like this

if ( currdate > data[date] {texbox turn green}
else {textbox turn red})

Answer (score 0):

Use the `DATEDIFF` function to do this.

Let's say you have a date variable from your database/php:

```
$date_variable = //put your date info from your database here
```

For current date, you can just use `NOW()`

So, it would look like this:

```
<?php 
if (DATEDIFF(NOW(), $date_variable) < 0) {
    /// do some stuff
} else {
//do some other different stuff
}
?>
```

Comment: no sure what you are trying to do, but could be > 0, or it could be < 0.....0 being the number of days difference between the 2 dates.

Answer (score 0):

A basic comparison will do if your dates are stored (or converted to) *Year-Month-Day*.

```
$d1="2013-03-06 00:00:00"; #DB value
$d2=date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); #Now
$c=($d1 > $d2) ? "#f44" : "#4f4";

echo "<input type='text' style='background-color:$c' value='$d1'>";
echo "<input type='text' value='$d2'>";
```